# Missing Required Positional Arguments while using fsolve in Python

Tags: python, scipy

I am writing a code to help simulate orbits of planets using fsolve and I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6ee902b5be74> in <module>
     11 
     12     # Backward Euler Method
---> 13     pn = p + dt*fsolve(nPointSystem, q, args = [m,G,n], xtol=1e-12)
     14     qn = q + dt*pn/mx3
     15 

TypeError: nPointSystem() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'G' and 'n'
```

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# mass of bodies
m = [1, 1/6023600, 1/408523.71, 1/328900.5614, 1/3098708, 1/1047.3486, 1/3497.898, 1/22902.98, 1/19412.24, 1/135200000]

# Initial positions
q = [[0.00450250884530125842,0.00076707348146464055,0.00026605632781203556],
   [0.35726020644727541518,-0.09154904243051842990,-0.08598103998694037053],
   [0.60824943318560406033,-0.34913244319590053792,-0.19554434578540693592],
   [0.11601490913916648627,-0.92660555364038517604,-0.40180627760698804496],
   [-0.11468858243909270380,-1.32836653083348816476,-0.60615518941938081574],
   [-5.38420940699214597622,-0.83124765616108382433,-0.22509475703354987777],
   [7.88988993382281817537,4.59571072692601301962,1.55843151672508969735],
   [-18.26990081497826660524,-1.16271158021904696130,-0.25036954074255487461],
   [-16.05954509192446441763,-23.94294829087950141524,-9.40042278035400838599],
   [-30.48782211215555045830,-0.87324543019672926542,8.91129698418475509659]]

# Initial velocities
qdot=[[-0.00000035174423541454,0.00000517762777222281,0.00000222910220557907],
      [0.00336784566219378527,0.02488934284224928990,0.01294407158679596663],
      [0.01095242010990883868,0.01561250673986247038,0.00632887645174666542],
      [0.01681162005220228976,0.00174313168798203152,0.00075597376713614610],
      [0.01448200480794474793,0.00023728549236071136,-0.00028374983610239698],
      [0.00109236329121849772,-0.00652329419119226767,-0.00282301226721943903],
     [-0.00321720349109366378,0.00433063223355569175,0.00192641746379945286],
      [0.00022154016562741063,-0.00376765355824616179,-0.00165324380492239354],
      [0.00264312279157656145,-0.00150349208075879462,-0.00068127100487234772],
      [0.00032256219593323324,-0.00314874792755160542,-0.00108017793159369583]]

# Gravitation Constant
G = 2.95912208286e-4

# Convert Lists to np arrays
m = np.array(m)
q = np.array(q)
qdot = np.array(qdot)

# Converting m from an nx1 to an nx3 array
mx3 = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(m, 1), 3, axis=1)

# Initial momentum
p = mx3 * qdot

# Time step in days
dt = 5

# number of planets
n = len(m)

def nPointSystem(q, m, G, n):
    pdot = np.zeros((n, 3))
    
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                q_len = np.linalg.norm(q[i,:]-q[j,:])
                pdot[i,:] -= G*m[i]*m[j]*(q[i,:]-q[j,:])/q_len**3   
    return pdot

# Time Stepper
    for i in range(1, 100):
    # Backward Euler Method
    pn = p + dt*fsolve(nPointSystem, q, args = [m,G,n], xtol=1e-12)
    qn = q + dt*pn/mx3
    
# Replace values of p and q
    p = pn
    q = qn
```

From what I can tell I am including the positional arguments I need. What I ultimately want to solve is

```
pn = p + dt*qn
qn = q + dt*pn/mx3
```

I am trying to numerically solve the orbits of planets in the solar system using the backward Euler formula (ultimately to show it doesn't work) and because of the backward Euler the formula needs to be solved implicitly, hence the use of fsolve. But no matter how I try to implement the arguments I get a similar error.

In fsolve I am using q as the guess point for the first value because it will be somewhat close to the next calculated value.

Comment: Try making the `args` argument to `fsolve` a tuple instead of a list.  It's documented to be a tuple, and some parts of Python are sensitive to that.   Your indentation is also wrong at the end of the code, but that was probably a copying error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, That is one of the things I have tried as well. When I change the line to:
pn = p + dt*fsolve(nPointSystem, q, args = (m,G,n), xtol=1e-12)
 instead I get an error of "IndexError: too many indices for array"

Comment: That's a completely different problem.  Your variables `q` and `dot` appear to be 2-dimensional arrays in which the size of the first dimension is 1.  You're using `q[i:i]` where `i` is completely out of range.  I'm not quite sure what you intend.